Docusaurus i18n not working when changing language
I have a docusaurus site set up with two languages, containing the same content. Most of the files have the same path (relative from root and the i18n directory), but I use slugs to translate the URLs to make more sense in the secondary language.
Changing language from the front page works with no problem, but doing it from within an article fails with a http404, when Docusaurus simply tries to switch to the translated article by changing the language prefix.
As far as I've seen in the docs, it should be possible to switch language and be redirected to the translated version of the article. This doesn't work however, even if I specify the ID in the articles front matter - the ID is the same across the languages, so not sure why it doesn't work. I would assume that when you change language, Docusaurus will look for the same ID in the language you change to, and then load it and apply the slugs, but it doesn't work for me.
Is there anything in particular I need to do, or do I have to choose between a sensible language switching behavior or the use of slugs in Docusaurus?
